# Dropdownlist not holding value after linkbutton click

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

I am trying to save quantity using dropdownlist used in Gridview. 
I have `<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Edit" Text="Change"></asp:LinkButton>` which changes gridview column to dropdownlist and then a save link button `<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Save" ></asp:LinkButton>` to save it in gridview column. 

 When I click on chnage it shows dropdownlist and i can select desired number however when i click on save it gets back to default ie; 1.
I tried using`OnSelectIndexChange` however breakpoint doesnt goes there.
I Also tried using `AutoPostBack="False"` and `EnableViewState="false"` but of no use.

 Heres my Markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="slno" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="100%" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">
     <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
      <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="slno" HeaderText="Sl No" ReadOnly="true">
         <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
           <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
      </asp:BoundField>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="itemname" HeaderText="Item Name" ReadOnly="true">
         <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
           <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
      </asp:BoundField>
     <asp:BoundField DataField="Rate" HeaderText="Price" ReadOnly="true">
         <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
           <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
     </asp:BoundField>
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="headerStyle" HeaderText="Quantity">
     <EditItemTemplate>
         <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlqty" runat="server" DataTextField='<%# Bind("qty") %>' AutoPostBack="false" EnableViewState="true">

             <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>

             <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>

             <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>

             <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>

             <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
                                                                                                                 </asp:DropDownList>
   </EditItemTemplate>

   <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Label ID="lblqty" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("qty") %>'></asp:Label>
   </ItemTemplate>

   <HeaderStyle CssClass="headerStyle" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
     <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
</asp:TemplateField>
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="headerStyle">
                                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Save" ></asp:LinkButton>
                                                <%--<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>--%>
                                            </EditItemTemplate>
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Edit" Text="Change"></asp:LinkButton>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <HeaderStyle CssClass="headerStyle" />
                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="30px" Font-Size="Small" />
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="total" HeaderText="Total" ReadOnly="true">
                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                        </asp:BoundField>
                                    </Columns>
                                    <EditRowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" BackColor="#999999" />
                                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" ForeColor="#333333" Font-Bold="True" />
                                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" ForeColor="White" />
                                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
                                </asp:GridView>
```

I am using code used by a friend and it works fine on his project. 
SO please help what am I missing here.

Comment: Did you wrap the binding of the GridView inside `if (!Page.IsPostBack) { //bind grid here }`

Comment: Yes `protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                BindGV();
            }]' BindGV has the code for binding

Answer (score 0):

Try `EnableViewState="true"` may it work